# Subtract previous list from current list in a list of lists loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dataframes with data duplicating in every next dataframe within list which I need to subtract between themselves

`the_list[0] = [1, 2, 3]
the_list[1] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

There are also df headers. Dataframes are only different in number of rows.

Wanted solution:

`the_list[0] = [1, 2, 3]
the_list[1] = [4, 5, 6, 7]`

Due to the fact that my list of lists, `the_list`, contains several dataframes, I have to work backward and go from the last df to first with first remaining intact.

My current code (estwin is the_list):

```
estwin = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
output=([])
    estwin.reverse()
    for i in range(len(estwin) -1):
        difference = Diff(estwin[i], estwin[i+1])
        output.append(difference)
    return(output)

def Diff(li_bigger, li_smaller): 
    c = [x for x in li_bigger if x not in li_smaller]
    return (c)
```

Currently, the result is an empty list. I need an updated `the_list` that contains only the differences (no duplicate values between lists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to go backward for this problem, it is easier to keep track of what you have already seen going forward.
Keep a set that gets updated with new items as you traverse through each list, and use it to filter out the items that should be present in the output.

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
estwin = [list1, list2]
lookup = set() #to check which items/numbers have already been seen.
output = []
for lst in estwin:
    updated_lst = [i for i in lst if i not in lookup] #only new items present
    lookup.update(updated_lst)
    output.append(updated_lst)  
print(output) #[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: This will work, but I do have column headers in lists within the_list. The output is somehow only the headers.

Comment: hmm, strange. What shape and datatype is the items in your real "the_list" in? can you show a snippet of it?  @r357

Comment: Specifically,  are you really sure you are working with lists?

Comment: I'm sorry, I got a bit carried away while writing the post. I actually have dataframes within the_list.

Comment: Ah, i see i see. Let me just ask someone and try to figure out if it would be better to post the question on dataframes as a separate question or modify this one as-is. Im not sure what approach is appropriate here. With dataframes specifically though, what are you looking to "avoid duplicating" so to speak? Is it column names, rows, or whatnot? @r357

Comment: I have a df populated with values and a dummy column. whenever the dummy is 1 I split the dataframe into (pseudo) df[:dummy=1-n for every dummy=1] with n being number of rows before the dummy. I need these slices in order to continue, but these slices are currently all from 0 to dummy, which is fine if I remove from next df slice whatever is already included in the previous df slice.

Comment: wait, so shouldnt the length suffice? @r357 the length of the 2nd last dataframe IIUC would be where the last dataframe "starts" having new rows.

Comment: Actually, it would. BUT I have this line which splits the df into chunks: estwin = [estwin.iloc[0:i-n] for i in idx] where idx is a list of indices where dummy=1. How do I wrap this in a loop so that i can do df[len(previous_df):i-n]?

Comment: At this point, im probably just concerned you might be going down a rabbit hole that you wouldn't want to get into in the first place. Is splitting the Df really the right call in the first place? You may want to just think through the steps that forced you to split the DF, and see if you could do them better. This might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not runnable, but if I guess what you meant to write, it works, except that you have one bug in your algorithm:

```
the_list = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
]

def process(lists):
    output = []
    lists.reverse()
    for i in range(len(lists)-1):
        difference = diff(lists[i], lists[i+1])
        output.append(difference)
    # BUGFIX: Always add first list (now last becuase of reverse)
    output.append(lists[-1])
    output.reverse()
    return output

def diff(li_bigger, li_smaller):
    return [x for x in li_bigger if x not in li_smaller]

print(the_list)
print(process(the_list))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Comment: It would be nice to see the printed feedback ;).

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
from itertools import chain

l = [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

new_l = [sorted(list(set(v).difference(chain.from_iterable(l[:num]))))
        for num, v in enumerate(l)]

print(new_l)
# [[1, 2], [3], [4], [5]]
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made. You are assuming:  order is not important, duplicates are not important (even if they are not removed) - etc - notihing in the original post leads to these assumptions.